Why are explicitly defaulted comparison operators deleted when the class contains a reference member?
I tried to default both operator== and operator<=> in a simple class that contains a reference member like that:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Simple
{
public:
    Simple(const std::string& data)
     : data_(data)
    {
    }

    auto operator<=>(const Simple&) const = default;

private:
    const std::string& data_;
};

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "one";
    Simple s1(str1);
    std::string str2 = "two";
    Simple s2(str2);
    std::cout << (s1 < s2) << std::endl; // compiler error

    return 0;
}

clang compiler states that
warning: explicitly defaulted three-way comparison operator is implicitly deleted
note: defaulted 'operator<=>' is implicitly deleted because class 'Simple' has a reference member

I got no warnings from other compilers (e.g. MSVC), but when I try to use it, I get compile errors:
<source>(62): error C2280: 'auto Simple::operator <=>(const Simple &) const': attempting to reference a deleted function
<source>(49): note: see declaration of 'Simple::operator <=>'
<source>(49): note: 'auto Simple::operator <=>(const Simple &) const': function was implicitly deleted because 'Simple' data member 'Simple::data_' of type 'const std::string &' is a reference type
<source>(52): note: see declaration of 'Simple::data_'

Other defaulted functions like copy assignment will of course be deleted, because they are not possible with a reference member.
But why can't the content a reference points to not be automatically compared?
And what is the shortest way to implement it manually?

Maybe because there are two definitions of equality here? this->data == other.data or &this->data == &other.data

[class.compare.default#2] "A defaulted <=> or == operator function for class C is defined as deleted if any non-static data member of C is of reference type or C has variant members ([class.union.anon])."

The issue here is that operator<=> and operator== cannot be defaulted in classes with reference members because the default implementations rely on comparing all data members directly. However, references don't support copy assignment or move operations, so the compiler can't synthesize these operators when references are involved.
When the compiler tries to default the operator<=>, it attempts to compare each member individually. But since data_ is a reference, it doesn't have a value of its own — it only points to another object, so the compiler can't perform direct comparisons like it would for a value type. That’s why the comparison operator is implicitly deleted.
You’ll need to implement operator== and operator<=> manually to compare the object the reference points to rather than the reference itself. Here’s how you can do it:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <compare>

class Simple
{
public:
    Simple(const std::string& data)
        : data_(data)
    {
    }

    bool operator==(const Simple& other) const
    {
        return data_ == other.data_;
    }

    auto operator<=>(const Simple& other) const
    {
        return data_ <=> other.data_;
    }

private:
    const std::string& data_;
};

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "one";
    Simple s1(str1);
    std::string str2 = "two";
    Simple s2(str2);
    
    std::cout << (s1 < s2) << std::endl;  // Works now

    return 0;
}


operator==: We manually define operator== to compare data_ in s1 and s2 by comparing the objects they reference.

operator<=>: Similarly, we manually define operator<=> to compare data_ in s1 and s2 using operator<=> on std::string. Since data_ is a reference, data_ <=> other.data_ performs a comparison between the std::string objects that the references point to.


Since references are not values themselves, they need to be compared by the objects they reference. This manual implementation works around the compiler's inability to default operator== and operator<=> for types with reference members. This is the shortest and cleanest way to handle the situation without changing the design of the class.

This does not explain why the default implementation could not just use the referenced value itself. After all, it would be simple enough.

And as "references don't exist" (they are not c++ objects) using the referred to object would make sense.

The logic is non-sequitur: Why would one need copy/move to compare referenced objects?  Given that our data == other.data is exactly how default == is specified, one would expect the same behaviour as for non-reference members.  I think the truth of the matter is an excess of caution (or shortage of time) when the committee chose to use the same rules as for defaultable copy/move.

@TobySpeight: If a car dealer has two inventory records, each with a VIN (Vehicle Identification Number), and the only difference between the car having with the first VIN and the one with the second VIN is the stamping on the VIN plate, should they be viewed as matching or non-matching?  If the goal is to aggregate identical cars to faciliate the process of finding cars that match customer requirements, they should be considered identical.  If the goal is to figure out how much warehouse space will be needed to hold all the cars, they need to be considered distinct.

@j6t, when you're comparing indirectly-included objects (pointers or references), it's ambiguous whether you want a shallow comparison (do these point to the same object?) or a deep comparison (do these point to objects that compare equal?).

That's a valid point @supercat.  I guess I'd expect it to work using the data member's <=> as if we'd written by hand (we wouldn't normally write &data <=> &other.data in a comparison).  Continuing your line of thought, we might believe that having a pointer as a member would inhibit default comparisons - but that's not the case, so it's not really a consistent argument for the current position.

@TobySpeight: I'd view a pointer as being more akin to a "vehicle identification NUMBER", which should be treated in a manner agnostic as to what it might represent,  and a reference as being more of a shorthand way of referring to a particular CAR.

Paper P1603R1 specifies that reference members should lead to deleted comparison operators saying that this is in accordance with paper P0515:

P0515 clearly lays out the design intent as comparison following copying, emphasis mine:

This proposal unifies and regularizes the noncontroversial parts of previous proposals, and incorporates EWG direction to pursue three-way comparison, letting default copying guide default comparison, and having a simple way to write a memberwise comparison function body.


The paper goes on to say (this time it's my emphasis):

It’s the safest rule for now and is most consistent with the design intent as laid out in P0515.

That is, the safest choice was made, and if sufficient motivation for a change of rules is brought forward, a change could be made.

Perhaps that's a different interpretation of "guide" than I would have had (I would have read that as setting the principle that it's implemented member-by-member using the same operator, rather than that it's inapplicable to reference members).

The reference members indeed prevent the compiler from generating the default comparison operators, because you can either compare the content the reference refers to, or the addresses.

what is the shortest way to implement it manually?

You can implement operator<=> manually in the following way:
auto operator<=>(const Simple& other) const
{
    return data_ <=> other.data_;
}

Godbolt demo.
You can similarly implement operator== for checking equality.

I don't completely understand the rationale, since I use a reference, not a pointer. A pointer definitely has two easily accessible values to compare, the address and the data at the address. But a reference should be transparent, you cannot directly get the address from it, only with &data_, which you could do with any variable type, therefore defaulting of comparison would not be possible for any variable type...

@mgr I agree it could have been like that (although under the hood a reference is similar to a pointer), but in practice it isn't. Unforetunatly I do not know why it was defined like that in the standard (since I am not a language lawyer, I  cannot quote it). However the practical solution is quite straightforward.

how can you extend the solution if you have several member variables?

@mgr std::tie(data1, data2, data3) <=> std::tie(other.data1, other.data2, other.data3)

@mgr for more than one member variable you can do something like this demo.

@j6t just saw your suggestion with std::tie - it's even better than my suggestion in the demo above.

@j6t nice trick!

@j6t, that can be made easier and less error-prone with a private helper: constexpr auto sortkey() const { return std::tie(data1, data2, data3); }.  Then <=> implementation is simply sortkey() <=> other.sortkey() - and == likewise.

I'll answer the final question: "what's the shortest way to implement this manually?"
I think the minimal change would be just to change the type of the data member:
    // include <functional>
    const std::reference_wrapper<const std::string> data_;

    constexpr auto operator<=>(const Simple&) const = default;
    constexpr auto operator==(const Simple&) const = default;

We may need to adapt the code slightly to call data_.get() where implicit conversion doesn't kick in for us (e.g. when calling member functions and - if it were writeable - assigning to the referent).

If we don't want to change the type, then I recommend using std::tie to create a comparable tuple of reference wrappers.  I usually write a small sortkey() function to ensure that the tuples are consistent:
private:
    constexpr auto sortkey() const
    {
        // include <tuple>
        return std::tie(data_);
    }

public:
    constexpr auto operator<=>(const Simple& other) const
    {
        return sortkey() <=> other.sortkey();
    }

    constexpr auto operator==(const Simple& other) const
    {
        return sortkey() == other.sortkey();
    }

The sortkey() function seems silly in this simple example with just a single member, but I hope you see how it extends to the more general case (with no changes needed to the operator functions as we add members).

In general, I recommend the first option, as it means you don't need to keep sortkey() up to date as you add member variables to the class.

Nice touch, +1 (I think using std::reference_wrapper is indeed a better option).
